# Qt GUI in Visual Studio..New Added Widgets through Qt Designer inaccessible

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I wrote an application in Visual Studio and I needed to create a GUI for it so I decided to use Qt and I'm having a small but weird problem.

Let's say I add a Push button to the GUI in the Qt Designer. When I build the Application the UI Compiler creates the corresponding header file "ui_myApp.h" which has the new Push button.

When I Try to access the new Button and connect Signals and Slots the I can't find the Button. I only see old Widgets that I added before the Last build. It actually should show me "pushButton_2" and "pushButton_3" but I have only access to the pushButton and other Widgets before the last build.(See Figure)

[image: 1edd5ce5-a688-480e-ac5e-bbe03bfe8cc8-image.png]

I Checked the headerfile "ui_myApp.h" and the new Widgets are actually there. The Header file is correctly included. When I run my Application the new Button and new Widgets are there too. Why can't I access them when Connecting Signals and Slots in "myApp.cpp"??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

This may or may not help anyone. But if anyone ever faces the problem here how I solved it:

Each time I add new Widgets to my GUI using QT Designer I save the changes in the Form. Then I clean the Solution and Rebuild. Then I close Visual Studio and start it again. The new Widgets are accessible after these action. Not sure why.. but it does the job.